# Is it safe to move a subversion working copy to a new computer using xcopy?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have many subversion checkouts (~50) some of which are quite large (hundreds of MB). To check each of these out again over the internet will take hours/days. Is it safe to just copy the whole directory structure to the same location on my new computer?

Nick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is safe.  Make sure you get all of the "hidden" .svn directories and that the version of subversion you're running on the new computer is at least as new as the one on the old computer.   If you try to run an older version of subversion on the new computer, it will most likely fail.

Comment: One more: make sure the OS is the same. Meaning: you can't move the working copy from e.g. linux to windows (different eol styles), or from a 32-bit windows to a 64-bit windows. It may work on the first few days, but you'll eventually end up with a corrupted working copy.